# One-One join in R

Tags: r

There are two files and the data looks like this:
file1

```
Col1   Col2  
**A**      10  
**B**      20   
**C**      30   
**D**      40
```

file2:

```
Col1   col2   
**A**   XYZ  
**B**   PQR  
**B**   QES  
**C**   UIY  
**D**   UUI  
**D**   HUI  
**E**   BIG
```

I want to join these two files on col1 1 ,but I want only those entries where we have one to one mapping only. The output shoul look like this:
file A (where we have match)
    **A** 10  XYZ
    **C** 30  UIY

file B (Where we don't found a  one to one map)

col1  col2
B  20
D  40

AS B and D have multiple entries in file 2, so I don't want these records in my join result.

Comment: Related merge post: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `inner_join` after subsetting the second dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
   group_by(Col1) %>% 
   filter(n()==1) %>% 
   inner_join(., df1, by = "Col1")
#     Col1  col2  Col2
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
#1     A   XYZ    10
#2     C   UIY    30
```

Or to avoid duplicate elements, as @zx8754 suggested

```
res <- df2 %>%
        inner_join(., df1, by = "Col1") %>%
        group_by(Col1) %>%
        filter(n()==1)
```

To get the rows that are not in the 'res', do a `anti_join`

```
res %>%
    select(Col1, Col2) %>% 
    anti_join(df1, .)
#  Col1 Col2
#1    B   20
#2    D   40
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df2)[df1,  Col2 := Col2[.N==1],on = "Col1", by = .EACHI])
#   Col1 col2 Col2
#1:    A  XYZ   10
#2:    C  UIY   30
```

Comment: I would add filter after join, in case df1 has duplicated values.

Comment: I get the one which i have found a match now, I want to segregate those which don't have a match in df2 so there will be two file one: where there is a match and second: where we don't have a match. I will test your approach on my test dataset Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @HimanshuChawla  this is based on your example and it is working for that.

Comment: @HimanshuChawla  If it is a new problem, please consider to post as a new question.

Comment: Its not a new question its just an extension to the previous one

Comment: Just a quick one I  have 198 columns I cant right each name in select, I tried select(df1,1:198) but its not working....